# Captcha Problems

Tags: bug, captcha

When I try to login using my regular Stack Exchange account using Google Chrome, I get caught in an infinite loop ever since they started using the "match" Captcha. After selecting the proper response, the match grid disappears, the checkbox is checked and then...nothing happens.

How can I fix this? As of now I have had to use a new browser and a new identity to get around the match Captcha.

Comment: What specific site? Does the one at http://askubuntu.com/nocaptcha work?

Comment: tex.stackexchange.com, primarily. Is there a /nocaptcha option?

Comment: Yes there is, try that

Comment: Same problem. I have to come back here because I enter the information and nothing happens. This is with Chrome; with Safari, no issues.